# Using one Google Maps Activity, call a method using three different buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, android-layout

I have an android application in which I have 3 buttons and by pressing them I want to call three different Google maps markers, by using the same google maps activity.

**CLASS WITH 3 DIFFERENT BUTTONS**

```
package com.postgre.my_tourist_guide;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class Sightseeings extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView7;
    Button button7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sightseeings);
        textView7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        textView7.setText(String.valueOf(name));
    }

    public void openMapTrain(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivityTrain.class);
        intent.putExtra("map1","map1");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openMap2(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivityTrain.class);
        intent.putExtra("map2","map2");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openMap3(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivityTrain.class);
        intent.putExtra("map3","map3");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and then my GOOGLE MAPS ACTIVITY CODE

```
package com.postgre.my_tourist_guide;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.postgre.my_tourist_guide.databinding.ActivityMapsTrainBinding;

public class MapsActivityTrain extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsTrainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsTrainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("map1");
        intent.getStringExtra("map2");
        intent.getStringExtra("map3");

        if (name == "map1"){

        }
        LatLng lexainia = new LatLng(39.3254942, 23.053191);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lexainia).title("Marker in Lexainia Train Station"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lexainia, 18f));

        LatLng map2 = new LatLng(37.9577198, 23.6526767);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(map2).title("Marker in map2"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(map2, 18f));

        LatLng map3 = new LatLng(37.9577198, 23.6526767);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(map3).title("Marker in map3"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(map3, 18f));
    }
}
```

This is what I've done so far, but I can't find a way to use the same `onMapReady` method, to show the three different markers, when I am pressing the three buttons. It's obvious that I have to pass something using the intent class, but I don't know what.

Any help is appreciated!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nameofmap1 = intent.getStringExtra("map1");
    String nameofmap2 = intent.getStringExtra("map2");
    String nameofmap3 = intent.getStringExtra("map3");

    if (nameofmap1 != null){
        LatLng lexainia = new LatLng(39.3254942, 23.053191);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lexainia).title("Marker in Lexainia Train Station"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lexainia, 18f));
    } else if (nameofmap2 != null) {
        LatLng map2 = new LatLng(37.9577198, 23.6526767);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(map2).title("Marker in map2"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(map2, 18f));
    } else if (nameofmap3 != null) {
        LatLng map3 = new LatLng(37.9577198, 23.6526767);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(map3).title("Marker in map3"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(map3, 18f));
    }   
}
```